# How to create "Tasks" in GitLab "Issues" via the GitLab API

Tags: laravel, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, issue-tracking

I am in the process of creating an API that will accept and process POST requests from GitLab webhooks and in turn create "Tasks" for issues that were created in GitLab.

**Example Steps:**

1. Create an issue in GitLab.
2. GitLab makes a POST request to my API via the project's configured webhooks.
3. My API validates the GitLab instance and secret before processing the POST request.
4. The Controller identifies it as an issue that was created in GitLab.
5. The Controller then makes a few POST requests to the GitLab API to create "Tasks".

I already have everything created and it executes as expected, however, it creates new issues rather than "tasks" that are associated with existing issues. This ends up in an infinite loop between the GitLab webhooks and my API making POST requests to GitLab.

I need to refactor **step 5** above to create "Tasks" instead of "Issues". I have also seen "work items" somewhere but cannot seem to find relevant API documentation for it.

Here's the code I am using to try and create the "Tasks" that are associated with the issue that was created. `$subtasks` is an array with 4 subtasks listed, each with a *title* and *description*.

```
// Loop through the subtasks and create them.
foreach ( $subtasks as $subtask ) {
    try {
        // Create the subtask via the GitLab API.
        Http::withToken($gitlabAccessToken)->post("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$projectId/issues", [
            'title' => $subtask['title'],
            'description' => $subtask['description'],
            'parent_id' => $issueId
        ]);
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

Here's a screenshot of what I want to create via the GitLab API if it is possible.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYhc5.png)

Thank you.

Comment: According to the [Tasks docs page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/tasks.html) as of 9/18/2023, there is a known limitation with tasks as they cannot be accessed via the REST API. it looks like they're working on a Work Items API right now however that will include tasks, so I'd check out future releases to see if this is added.

Comment: @AdamMarshall Thank you for your feedback. Based on it, I have decided to rewrite parts of my API to use GitLab's GraphQL API instead and it's working perfectly. When I create an issue in GitLab, GitLab makes a POST request to the defined Webhook in the project which in turn makes POST requests to GitLab's GraphQL API to create the Work Items for the issue that was created. This will do for now until the Work Items API is available. Have a great day :)

Comment: Glad you found a workaround!